# Time Comparision for between

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, datatable

How do I check for time for between. suppose I have Time in string format like "02:00 PM" and I want to check it between two other times. How can I check for this, as the time is in string format ?
The value to be compare with the times is store in DataTable, and I am using the Select function of the datatable.

Comment: Don't store it in a string, put it into a DateTime, then you can easier compare the values.

Comment: One of the value is in the DataTable , how can I store it in the as I have to compare that value with the two values on my form control( date time control).

Comment: *Never* store a date or time in a string in your dbase table.  You'll have major culture hassles when your dbase is read by a machine in another country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always convert to string to a timespan (or datetime) something like this:

```
        TimeSpan ts = Convert.ToDateTime("02:00 PM").TimeOfDay;
        TimeSpan checkValue1 = Convert.ToDateTime("01:00 PM").TimeOfDay;
        TimeSpan checkValue2 = Convert.ToDateTime("03:00 PM").TimeOfDay;
        bool passed = (ts >= checkValue1 && ts <= checkValue2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `DateTime.Parse(dateString1) > DateTime.Parse(dateString2)`.

If your string format is not compatible with the string format of [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx), you'll need to parse your date manually.

Edit:
You can use [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) to specify your own format:

```
string Format = "T";
CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("en-US");
if (DateTime.ParseExact(dateString1, format, provider) >
      DateTime.ParseExact(dateString2, format, provider))
{
    ...
```

Comment: how can I compare it with the time in the DataTable? is there any way to compare the time in the dataTable ?

Comment: If your time in the DataTable is stored as string, you can get the time string from the DataTable and compare it as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a `DateTime` with the current date as date, or a `TimeSpan` representing the time from midnight:

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(timeString);
```

Or:

```
TimeSpan time = DateTime.Parse(timeString).TimeOfDay;
```

Having the value as a `TimeSpan` might be easier when you compare it, otherwise you have to make sure that the `DateTime` values that you compare it to also have the current date as date. On the other hand, the `DateTime` value can be used to compare times across midnight, e.g. between 23.00 today and 01.00 tomorrow.